# MVC4 deployment in IIS7.. 500 internal error

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-mvc-4

I have MVC4 which is running fine my local IISExpress. Today My admin created brand new Dev server and created new web application under default website. I have published same code into that webapplication folder. when I typed `http://dev.company.com/iapps/vol` it blows up `500 - Internal server error`

[image]

How can I troubleshoot this?

Comment: Did you check the application event log on that machine?

Comment: Make sure `customErrors` is set to off in `Web.config` and you should see a full error and stacktrace. Post it here

Answer (score 0):

There are like a million things that could be wrong (missing DLLs, file permissions, DB access, etc)
The easiest way start debugging the problem is accesing the site from inside the dev server. This way IIS will throw the error to the browser because it's local.

Answer (score 0):

Try registering ASP.NET.

From Windows Explorer, browse to:
C:\Windows\System32

Find cmd.exe, right click on it and "Run as administrator"

Then in run this:
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319>aspnet_regiis -i